# Установка приложений на iOS 5.1.1

Tags: ios, ipad

Купил себе б/у iPad первий, и не могу на него установить ни одного приложения, так как, что бы я не ставил через itunes, все требует минимум iOS 6.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли как-то обновится или установить совместимые с данной OS приложения.

Из приложение мне надо только pdf читалка и видео проигрыватель.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5.1.1 максимальная версия доступная для iPad первого поколения.

[Вот тут](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/141840/finding-old-versions-of-ios-apps-for-5-1-1-on-a-1st-generation-ipad) есть интересная идея, что можно сделать (сам не пробовал).

Примерный перевод:

Входишь в аппстор с компьютера (не подключая iPad). Находишь и скачиваешь приложения на компьютер. Когда они добавлены в библиотеку открываешь аппстор на iPad и устанавливаешь приложения. Поскольку новые версии работать не будут, система предложит установить последнюю совместимую версию. Работает примерно на 85% приложений.

Comment: Спасибо, но не получилось :(
говорит, что требуется мин. iOS 6
пробывал несколько разных приложений

Comment: Отключил функцию автоманической установки приложений с aппстор и все получилось. Спасибо!